# how to run script on remote machine with delay

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I want to run script on remote machine but with delay

for example

```
 scp -rp script root@$IP:/tmp

 ssh root@$IP:/tmp/script   ( but script will run after 5 sec )
```

- my target is - run the script with ... "no connection ...not via ssh

the target is to run the script with no connection from source machine ( not via ssh ) , so ssh will be only the trigger and after 5 sec script will run

Comment: Are you able to modify your script? If yes, you can add `sleep 5` at hte beginning of the script, otherwise you can run `ssh root@IP sleep 5 && /tmp/script`

Comment: is your ssh command actually `ssh root@$IP /tmp/script` (space instead of colon)?

Comment: and do you mean your "goal" is to run the script with ... "no connection ...not via ssh"? You then say that ssh *should* be the trigger. Do you want the script to run after the *scp*, or via ssh?

Comment: yes my target is -  run the script with ... "no connection ...not via ssh ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your resolution was minutes/hours/days and not seconds, you could use 'at':

```
ssh root@IP 'echo /tmp/script | at now + 5 minutes'
```

(Requires the at daemon, 'atd', to be running)

EDIT: If you do want seconds resolution, you can use 'sleep', but you have to redirect stdout and stderr in order for ssh to let go of the connection:

```
ssh root@IP "(sleep 5; /tmp/script) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &"
```

I found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/36436